# Can I program a new key for my Toyota Corolla 2013?

Tags: toyota, corolla, key, fob, smartkey

I just bought a used Toyota Corolla 2013 (manufactured 2013-03), but it only came with one key. Today, I called the local Toyota dealer to ask how much was a new key and they told me it was nearly 500 CAD (380 USD)!

The key in question also has 4 buttons on it (lock, unlock, trunk and panic). There is a `G` on the blade of the key.

Can I buy an identical blank (ideally Toyota OEM), with the 4 buttons and program it myself with no special equipment (of course I will have the key cut at a locksmith)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The key for your Corolla is called a "G-Chip" key. You can purchase the key online (just search for your year and "g-chip" ... ensure it has the fob built in). Unfortunately you would need a programmer to get the key attuned to your car. You'll need to find a locksmith who has a programmer, or you can take it to the dealership. Getting the key from online is going to be far cheaper than buying it from the dealership. Having a locksmith program it will be much cheaper than the dealership.

There is an option to do this yourself, but you'd have to purchase a programmer in order to do it. The programmer itself costs far in excess of just taking your car to the dealership, though.