# Is there a way to invalidate "old" keys on a Toyota Corolla 2013?

Tags: toyota, corolla, key, fob, smartkey

I just bought a used Toyota Corolla 2013 (manufactured 2013-03) but it only came with one key. Now I might be a little bit paranoid, but since I can't be sure that the seller kept another key I would like to know if there is a way to invalidate all the keys except mine (AFAIK these are chipped keys)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you get your new key programmed for your Corolla ([ref: this question](https://mechanics.stackexchange.com/q/45434/4152)), they can have any other keys programmed out of the vehicle. It has to be done with a special programmer.

Comment: Is this something a car locksmith can do or only a Toyota dealer can?

Comment: If the locksmith has the right programmer, they can do it. I believe a programmer which can add the G-chip key can also remove them. The [OBDStar Key Master](https://www.amazon.com/OBDSTAR-Programmer-Immobiliser-Adjustment-Function/dp/B01HB4TRII?th=1) or the like should be able to do it.